# Advance a regex forward one character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, capturing-group

I'm looking for expressions between a period and a semicolon - this expression cannot itself contain periods or semicolons.

Here is my regex so far.

`(?!\..*?\..*?;)\..*?;`

The regex basically says "Find string between a period and a semicolon. However, upon identifying a candidate period, if it is eventually followed by another period before reaching the semicolon, then I want to disqualify it."

This does what I want, except I don't want to include the initial period in the match (nor the terminal semicolon). I tried to move forward with a non-capturing group `(?!\..*?\..*?;)(?:\.).*?;` but I get the same result. How can I omit the period (and semicolon) as part of the match? I'm using Sublime 3 to search for regular expressions.

Comment: \.([^.]+); this can solve your problem i think

Comment: @CodeManiac He doesn't want the expression to actually match the period or semicolon - see `this expression cannot itself contain periods or semicolons.`

Comment: (?<=\.)([^.]+)(?=;) in that case this will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to use a negative character set instead, which will allow you to match any character *but* the ones you put in the set (exclude periods and semicolons). Then, use lookahead to check that the non-period characters are *followed* by a semicolon, without actually *matching* the semicolon, and use lookbehind to ensure that the pattern is immediately preceded by a period:

So, the pattern

```
(?<=\.)[^.;]+(?=;)
```

will match non-period, non-semicolon characters which are after a period and followed by a semicolon.

https://regex101.com/r/E8XsDB/2

Comment: I missed the ; in my regex your's is perfect

Comment: Mine is inferior, not just because it includes the periods and semi colons, but because in the following example, it will only match the latter case, not both: `a. a; a. a;`

Comment: Is there a reason why this regex can include newline characters while mine never does?

Comment: @efthimio The `.` in a pattern does not match newlines - it'll match *anything but a newline* character. Negative character sets, on the other hand, will match *absolutely anything* not in the character set.